# Kivy TextInput given to same variable

Tags: python, kivy

I'm making a Python program with a Graphical User Interface (GUI) using Kivy. This program has several tabs that contain 2 `TextInput` widgets combined with a submit button. To avoid having one variable per `TextInput` per tab (which would make many variables), I tried to assign all corresponding `TextInput` from different tabs to the same kv variable, i.e. using the same ids for all `TextInput` from different tabs. The content of the kv variables is given to two Python `ObjectProperty` variables. All the input types are the same (i.e. string).

When running the program and giving inputs in each tab, one after the other, the inputs of the first tab are empty (when printed in Python) while the inputs of the second tab work appropriately. When removing the duplicated ids from the second tab in the kv lang file (i.e. making the `TextInput` ids of the first tab unique again), the first tab input is captured correctly.

Hence, it seems that repeating the same ids across the same kv lang file leads to this incorrect input capturing behavior.

Here is a subset of my Python script (simplified as much as possible to summarize my issue):

```
class MyLayout(BoxLayout):

    # 2 inputs per tab
    type_text_input = ObjectProperty()  # 1st input
    amount_text_input = ObjectProperty()  # 2nd input
    all_tab_content = [[] for i in range(9)]
    regular_income_type = ObjectProperty()  # combined input

    def synchronizeTabContent(self, i):
        # Give (back) the value corresponding to the current tab to the ListAdapter
        self.regular_income_type.adapter.data = self.all_tab_content[i]

    def submit(self, i):
        # Get user inputs from the TextInputs
        combined_input = self.type_text_input.text + ":" + self.amount_text_input.text
        # Add string to the ListView and to the whole list
        self.regular_income_type.adapter.data.extend([combined_input])
        self.all_tab_content[i] = self.regular_income_type.adapter.data
        # Reset the ListView
        self.regular_income_type._trigger_reset_populate()


class SampleApp(App):
    def build(self):

        # Set the background color for the window
        Window.clearcolor = (0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1)
        return MyLayout()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sample_app = SampleApp()
    sample_app.run()
```

Here is a subset of my kv lang script:

```
<SubmitButton@Button>:
    text: "Submit"
    size_hint_x: 15

MyLayout:

<MyLayout>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    type_text_input: type_input  # variable which is empty in first tab
    amount_text_input: amount_input  # variable which is empty in first tab
    regular_income_type: students_list_view
    padding: 10
    spacing: 10

    #### Some layout code was skipped here ####

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"
        height: 30

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            size_hint_x: .25
            TabbedPanelItem:
                text: "Regular"
                on_press: root.synchronizeTabContent(4)

                # ----- First tab -----
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: "vertical"
                    size_hint_x: 1
                    BoxLayout:
                        size_hint_x: 0.95
                        size_hint_y: 0.1
                        height: "40dp"

                        Label:
                            color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
                            text: "Type"
                        TextInput:
                            id: type_input  # here is where is suspect the error comes from
                        Label:
                            color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
                            text: "Amount"
                        TextInput:
                            id: amount_input  # here is where is suspect the error comes from
                    BoxLayout:  # Button box
                        size_hint_y: 0.1
                        height: "40dp"
                        SubmitButton:
                            on_press: root.submit(4)

            # ----- End of first tab -----

            TabbedPanelItem:
                text: "Deposit"
                on_press: root.synchronizeTabContent(5)

                # ----- Second tab -----
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: "vertical"
                    size_hint_x: 1
                    BoxLayout:
                        size_hint_x: 0.95
                        size_hint_y: 0.1
                        height: "40dp"

                        Label:
                            color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
                            text: "Type"
                        TextInput:
                            id: type_input  # here is where is suspect the error comes from
                        Label:
                            color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
                            text: "Amount"
                        TextInput:
                            id: amount_input  # here is where is suspect the error comes from
                    BoxLayout:
                        size_hint_y: 0.1
                        height: "40dp"
                        SubmitButton:
                            on_press: root.submit(5)
```

The variables that store an empty string for any input of the first tab are `self.type_text_input` and `self.amount_text_input`. Their corresponding kv variables are `type_input` and `amount_input`, which are used once for each tab and specified as the `id` of the `TextInput`. I suspect the repeated use of the same ids to be responsible for my issue.

Is there a way to store the inputs of different `TextInput` in the same Python variable without using a different kv variable for each `TextInput`?

Comment: id's are unique, read [here](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#ids) that they're collected in a dictionary at the root level while the file is processed. This means if multiple identical id's are used, they overwrite each other. What you could do is programmantically re-assign `type_text_input` every time the user switches tabs.

Comment: Honestly, kivy's way of process-ordering, name-scoping and automatic value update propagation is one giant clusterf*ck that requires a lot of rote-learning in order to use properly. And the documentation is really poor and unorganized. Kivy has potential to become an awesome tool, but currently it's more of a private party for the developers. You will have many, many problems juts like this one where you don't even precisely know what part you didn't get, only that it doesn't behave the way you want it to. I would advise against kivy for that reason at the moment.

Comment: Like even the advice about `id`'s being unique is nothing more but a guess, derived from how dictionaries usually work in python. But there isn't a single mention about uniqueness inside the docs and how id's propagate exactly throughout a kivy widget. All you have is like 3 sentences, two of which are concerning an implementation detail that open up more question's than they answer. "The widget itself can be accessed with `<id>.__self__ (btn1.__self__ in)` this case"  wtf are they talking about, with whom, for what purpose?

Comment: It's indeed pretty challenging to get to use Kivy properly and to find these kind of very specific technical details in the documentation or on the forums. Do you have any idea of how to re-assign a variable when changing tab? I could manage to apply a Python method on press `on_press: root.synchronizeTabContent(4)`, but I can't figure out how to re-assign my variable on press in the kv lang file too.

Comment: @Nearoo I do agree that kivy has many quirks, and many times they drive me nuts, but unique ids are not one of them. I believe is common sense to have them. Otherwise what the program would return if you assign the same id to many objects? The first? The last? A random one?

Comment: @embryo I don't know. But that's exactly what makes kivy so tedious to use - _you don't know_. I agree that you could've thought that it is highly likely that id's are unique while reading the docs. But that kind of "probability assignment" of theories on how kivy works and reading between the lines is something you encounter all over kivy. It's tedious, wasted energy, and incredibly frustrating if you get it wrong, because you have 100 places where you could've interpreted something the wrong way. Zen of Python states "explicit is better than implicit" for a reason.

Comment: @embryo And it's not how you should document code. Otherwise you can just post the code and say "all the info you need is in there".

Comment: @BorisSchnider Assign different id's to each input, and then in your `synchronizeTabContent` you can assign the object the ids references to your `type_text_input`. Read more [here](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html).

Comment: @Nearoo I ended up using `ids` dictionary to access all my kv lang `id`s as a single variable in python. Do you want to make an answer to this topic as you guided me to this point or should I do it myself?

Comment: You do it, I don't want to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Nearoo, I assigned different `id`s to each `TextInput`, which I accessed from the `ids` variable in Python and thereby, I was able to retrieve all the user inputs in a single Python variable, without using `ObjectProperty` variables. `ids` variable is a dictionary, whose keys are the `id`s provided in the kv lang script and whose values are, in this case, the `TextInput`.

The final simplified Python code is:

```
class MyLayout(BoxLayout):

    # store all tab content
    all_tab_content = [[] for i in range(9)]

    def synchronizeTabContent(self, i):
        # Give (back) the value corresponding to the current tab to the ListAdapter
        self.ids["regular_income{}".format(i)].adapter.data = self.all_tab_content[i]

    def submit(self, i):
        # Get user inputs from the TextInputs
        combined_input = self.ids["type_input{}".format(i)].text + self.sep + self.ids["amount_input{}".format(i)].text
        # Add string to the ListView and to the whole list
        self.ids["regular_income{}".format(i)].adapter.data.extend([combined_input])
        self.all_tab_content[i] = self.ids["regular_income{}".format(i)].adapter.data
        # Reset the ListView
        self.ids["regular_income{}".format(i)]._trigger_reset_populate()


class SampleApp(App):
    def build(self):

        # Set the background color for the window
        Window.clearcolor = (0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1)
        return MyLayout()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sample_app = SampleApp()
    sample_app.run()
```

The final simplified kv lang code is:

```
<SubmitButton@Button>:
    text: "Submit"
    size_hint_x: 15

MyLayout:

<MyLayout>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    padding: 10
    spacing: 10

    #### Some layout code was skipped here ####

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"
        height: 30

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            size_hint_x: .25
            TabbedPanelItem:
                text: "Regular"
                on_press: root.synchronizeTabContent(4)

                # ----- First tab -----
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: "vertical"
                    size_hint_x: 1
                    BoxLayout:
                        size_hint_x: 0.95
                        size_hint_y: 0.1
                        height: "40dp"

                        Label:
                            color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
                            text: "Type"
                        TextInput:
                            id: type_input4  # each id is unique
                        Label:
                            color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
                            text: "Amount"
                        TextInput:
                            id: amount_input4  # each id is unique
                    BoxLayout:  # Button box
                        size_hint_y: 0.1
                        height: "40dp"
                        SubmitButton:
                            on_press: root.submit(4)
                                    ListView:
                                        size_hint_y: 0.2
                                        id: regular_income4
                                        adapter:
                                            ListAdapter(data=[], cls=main.StudentListButton)


            # ----- End of first tab -----

            TabbedPanelItem:
                text: "Deposit"
                on_press: root.synchronizeTabContent(5)

                # ----- Second tab -----
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: "vertical"
                    size_hint_x: 1
                    BoxLayout:
                        size_hint_x: 0.95
                        size_hint_y: 0.1
                        height: "40dp"

                        Label:
                            color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
                            text: "Type"
                        TextInput:
                            id: type_input5  # each id is unique
                        Label:
                            color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
                            text: "Amount"
                        TextInput:
                            id: amount_input5  # each id is unique
                    BoxLayout:
                        size_hint_y: 0.1
                        height: "40dp"
                        SubmitButton:
                            on_press: root.submit(5)
                                    ListView:
                                        size_hint_y: 0.2
                                        id: regular_income5
                                        adapter:
                                            ListAdapter(data=[], cls=main.StudentListButton)
```

(Note that `ListView` and `ListAdapter` objects were added for the purpose of the program and were therefore used as keys of `ids` in `synchronizeTabContent` and `submit` methods.)